# pushing in git hub files

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell me

```
     .interpolate("monotone")
     and 
     .ease("monotone")
```

but it still moves jumpy.

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, you are maxing out my CPU.  I suspect that the animation cannot keep up consistently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're popping the data off the front while the easing is still taking place. You may have your smooth animation, but because you're shifting the data window every second (adding new data at one end and removing old data), you're seeing this jump.

You'll want to use [`transition.each`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each) to call a method after the completion of each transition and remove the data points then.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. but I am not sure about what you said. Can you please provide me some code. I do not know where to edit.